# Rally GetByReference returning null

Tags: c#, rally

I am querying for a `PortfolioItem/Mmf`. This works fine:

```
new Request("PortfolioItem/Mmf")
            {
                ProjectScopeUp = false,
                ProjectScopeDown = true,
                Fetch = new List() { "Name", "Description", "FormattedID", "LastUpdateDate", "Owner", "Children" },
                Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, _formattedID)
            };
```

But when I query for the ref address (which I can open on my browser and check the json perfectly) like this:

```
//_childFetch contains the same Fetch string list from the previous query
var childObject = m_rallyApi.GetByReference(_childRef, _childFetch);
```

it returns null.

Why does this not work? Both Queries work when it is a hierarchical requirement.

**Edit**
Full code of the method using the GetByReference()

```
private HierarchicalRequirement GetUserStoryByReference(string _childRef, string[] _childFetch)
        {
            HierarchicalRequirement userStory = null;

            var childObject = m_rallyApi.GetByReference(_childRef, _childFetch);

            if (childObject["Children"].Count == 0)
            {
                userStory = new HierarchicalRequirement(childObject);
            }
            else
            {
                if (childObject["Children"].Count > 0)
                {
                    userStory = new HierarchicalRequirement(childObject);

                    foreach (var child in childObject["Children"])
                    {
                        userStory.Children.Add(GetUserStoryByReference(child["_ref"], _childFetch));
                    }
                }
            }
            return userStory;
        }
```

Comment: can you provide the code that contains the `var childObject = m_rallyApi.GetByReference(_childRef, _childFetch);` please

Comment: Sure, but I think is not important

Comment: Are you using the `RallyRestToolkitFor.NET` on GitHub or something else?

Comment: I guess not, I'm using a dll downloaded from their developer web page. The github one more recent?

Comment: 2 things I would look for,  1. that the values being passed in are not null. and 2. I might try to add `[]` after `_childFetch` like `_childFetch[]` in your Variable Declaration, just for giggles. oh and 3. I would check to make sure that the m_rallyApi will take an Array as a parameter for the GetByReference (which it most likely does and you have probably already checked these things)

Comment: are you getting a NullReferenceException or is userStory just Null when it is returned?

Comment: Just null, no exceptions. I'm guaranteed that both args are not null or empty and are valid. The signature of the method is a string and a string[], and besides that it is working the the ref args references a hierarchicalrequirement. I also changed my dll right now for the one in github but nothing changed.

Comment: One more thing: when I try to access the ref address with my free account I get: `{"OperationResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "1", "_rallyAPIMinor": "40", "Errors": ["Requested type name \"portfolioitem/mmf\" is unknown."], "Warnings": ["API status is Deprecated and will become Not Supported on 2014-03-15"]}}`, but when I access it with a full account I was provided it works normally. And I am using this full account to authenticate off course.

Comment: add that to the Question, you might have to look through the API Documentation.  I can only troubleshoot this so far, as I don't have experience with rally only C#.

Comment: /portfolioitem/mmf is a custom PI Type that has been setup specific to the workspace in your paid subscription. That's why it doesn't work in your free account, FWIW...

Comment: Thanks Mark, I thought so. But it is not the origin of my problem, for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a defect. I get

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
```

when using

```
String featureRef = queryResults.Results.First()._ref; 
Console.WriteLine(featureRef); //prints correctly
DynamicJsonObject feature = restApi.GetByReference(featureRef, "Name");
String name = feature["Name"];
```

The last line is where it chokes. 
Identical code with UserStories and its Children works.

If I avoid `GetByReference` it works with PortfolioItems. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace FindTFchildren
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RallyRestApi restApi;
            restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");

            String projectRef = "/project/12352814790";     //replace this OID with an OID of your project


            Request fRequest = new Request("PortfolioItem/Feature");
            fRequest.Project = projectRef;
            fRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            fRequest.Fetch = new List<string>() { "FormattedID", "Name", "UserStories"};
            fRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "F3");
            QueryResult queryResults = restApi.Query(fRequest);


            foreach (var f in queryResults.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FormattedID: " + f["FormattedID"] + " Name: " + f["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Collection ref: " + f["UserStories"]._ref);
                Request childrenRequest = new Request(f["UserStories"]);
                QueryResult queryChildrenResult = restApi.Query(childrenRequest);
                foreach (var c in queryChildrenResult.Results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FormattedID: " + c["FormattedID"] + " Name: " + c["Name"]);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I guess it is really a bug this time. For the time being, I guess I will iterate every `feature` child of a MMF and query using the normal Request object. I think is the best turn around for now.